# How to get an uploads url from amazon s3 service with node. (Auto signed)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, amazon-s3, mongoose

I am attempting to use node to upload a file to a s3 server. I can do this successfully. However, the reason of using s3 is i need to upload a file for a users profile picture. How would i get the url(of the uploaded file in s3) in my code and store it in the db, so it is viewable on the frontend? I also need to append some kind of unique string to the file name, therefore it doesn't get overwritten. How would i go about doing this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
function uploadFileToS3Bucket(filePath) {
    AWS.config.update({
        accessKeyId: 'AWS ACCESS KEY',
        secretAccessKey: 'AWS SECRETE KEY'
    });
    var s3 = new AWS.S3();
    var params = {
        Bucket: 'AWS_BUCKET_NAME',
        Body: fs.createReadStream(filePath),
        Key: "BB_Teams_PDF_" + Date.now() + "_" + path.basename(filePath)
    };
    s3.upload(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error", err);
        }
        //success
        if (data) {
            console.log("Uploaded in:", data.Location);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much bro. Just one more thing i need. Files uploaded to s3 need to be unique right, so how would you assign a unique string to a file url, therefore it isn't overwritten and you can still access it? Is this what you are doing in the key property in the params object? If so how does it work as i currently don't understand it's implementation.

Comment: Date.now() + "_" + path.basename(filePath)  This line will create new string every time because of timestamp which will always be unique

Comment: Thanks bro. And if i were to use something such as postman, where the a file is chosen from something such as file explorer, how would i set the key to that location. Would i replace "BB_Teams_PDF_" with req.files.file and that would do it?

Comment: just concatenate file name with timestamp to make it unique

Comment: Thanks. But "BB_Teams_PDF_" is the name of the file your uploading right? You are specifying a file however i want a user to select one from something like file explorer. So what would i replace  "BB_Teams_PDF_" with? req.files.file or something?

Comment: Yes from the files object you can also get the original file name

Comment: Oh ok, so how would you get the original filename. What would the code look like? req.files....?

Comment: You can give any name what you want it hard-coded it with the timestamp

Comment: Yes please brother

Comment: And please don't specify a file, please use the req.files or something so then user can select a file. Thanks so much bro. Because i need the user to be able to select a file, so how would i get the original file name using req.files so i file can be selected brother?

Comment: Also brother, where do the accessKeyId and secretAccessKey come from, what do i set them to?

Comment: AccessId and secretAccessKey come from the aws account from which you have created you bucket

Comment: Thanks bro. In the code what is the body for (in the params), and what does fs.createReadStream(filePath) do? And where does filepath come from? Plus how does the data value work in s3 upload?

Comment: Please help on this brother?

Comment: For the details information about fs visit on https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/advanced/streams/how-to-use-fs-create-read-stream/ and check the aws doc for s3 working

Comment: hey thanks bro. But in the frontend, i am using flutter, so how would i get the url from the backend to the frontend, to display image on frontend?